# Calculate Array values using For-In Loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript. I am trying to calculate the total of the myCosts array values using the 'for in; loop and then display them on the page. I think i am nearly there.

```
function enterFood() 
{ 
    var myFoods = new Array() 
    var myCosts = new Array() 

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    { 
        myFoods[i] = prompt("Enter name of Food",""); 
        myCosts[i] = parseFloat(prompt("Enter cost of food","")); 
        document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML += i + ". " + myFoods[i] + ". Cost: £" + myCosts[i] + "<br />"; 
    } 

    for (var i in myCosts) 
    { 
        document.getElementById("total_cost").innerHTML =+ i; 
    } 
}
```

Can anybody offer any help so I can complete this?

Comment: sidenote: [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Comment: How is it not working for you?  Expected results versus generated results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `var` keyword before the `i` in the for loop. Without it `i` will become a global variable. Also, using the array literal notation (`[]`) is shorter/faster/cleaner than writing `new Array()`, like so: `myArray = []`; Just a general tip... Also note that `for (var ... in ...)` is used to iterate through the members of an object and generally not to loop through an array.

If you're not using the values in the `myBooks` and `myPrices` arrays later in your script then you don't need any arrays here - you can just combine your two loops and save the values returned from the prompts in temporary variables inside the loop.  See below:

```
function enterFood()
{
    var total_cost = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    { 
        var name = prompt("Enter name of Food","");
        var cost = parseFloat(prompt("Enter cost of food","")); 
        document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML += i + ". " + name + ". Cost: £" + cost + "<br />";
        total_cost += cost;
    }
    document.getElementById("total_cost").innerHTML = total_cost;
}
```

Additionally just looking at your code have a few comments:

**1)** Missing `var` keyword before the `i` inside the for loop. Without it i will become a GLOBAL variable.

**2)** In Javascript an array is an object, it has various properties that are functions. Using the array literal notation (i.e. `[]` ) is cleaner/shorter and faster than writing `new Array`..for example `myArray = []`

**3)** The For-In loop is used to iterate through the members of an object and generally NOT to loop through an array. For-In loops are slower than normal loops. You want to use a regular loop for iterating over an array.

**4)** If you are not using the values in the `myBooks` and `myPrices` arrays later on in your script then you do not need any arrays here, you could just combine your 2 loops and save the values returned from the prompts inside temporary variables inside the loop.

EDIT: As corrected by [@Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu), `i` is hoisted from `for..in` loop so will not become global.

Comment: Actually `i` won't become global, it's hoisted from `for..in` loop.

Comment: thanks @Teemu you are right. I have added an edit with your correction.

Comment: Oh, how I sometimes envy you, native English speakers! You can write really huge texts out of piece of nothing in a couple of minutes...

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate array correctly:

```
var totalElement = document.getElementById("total_cost"),
    total_cost = parseFloat(totalElement.innerHTML);

for (var i = 0, len < myCosts.length; i < len; i++) {
    total_cost += myCosts[i];
}

totalElement.innerHTML = total_cost;
```